# Safari font color with JavaScript wrong and no colour in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, safari

I have been battling with a minor issue in a project that I am on at the moment.

I am using the following script to colour format the form structure (html below). Note this is a prototype so the data is static

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

     document.getElementsByClassName("dueDate");
     document.getElementsByClassName("premium");
     var bills = document.getElementsByClassName("status");

     for (i in bills) {
       var dueDate = document.getElementsByClassName("dueDate")[i];
       var premium = document.getElementsByClassName("premium")[i];
       var status = document.getElementsByClassName("status")[i];

      /* Mark bills due to be paid: Green */
      if (status.value == "DUE") {
        dueDate.style.color = "green";
        <!-- Error here:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined-      ->
        premium.style.color = "green";
        status.style.color = "green";
      }
    /* Mark bills unpaid and overdue: Red to signify ACTION REQUIRED */
      else if (status.value == "UNPAID") {
        dueDate.style.color = "red";
        premium.style.color = "red";
        status.style.color = "red";
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="billPanel">
 <form>
  <input type="text" class="dueDate" name="dueDate" value="23 Jan 14" disabled />
  <input type="text" class="premium" name="premium" value="$20,000" disabled />
  <input type="text" class="status" name="status" value="DUE" disabled />
</form>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="dueDate" name="dueDate" value="23 Dec 14" disabled />
  <input type="text" class="premium" name="premium" value="$45,000" disabled />
  <input type="text" class="status" name="status" value="UNPAID" disabled />
</form>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="dueDate" name="dueDate" value="23 Nov 14" disabled />
  <input type="text" class="premium" name="premium" value="$22,000" disabled />
  <input type="text" class="status" name="status" value="PAID" disabled />
</form>
```

This all renders nicely in Chrome and Firefox but in safari the green is lurid and the default text un-effected by the script is a washed out grey not the black I wanted. In Internet explorer the script does't work at all.

Chrome shows the following error after the first call to dueDate.style.color = "green";

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

I have tried the hex value for green with the same results.

Another version of this script shows/hides a pay now button is shown to fail in Chrome dev tools around where it modifies the appearance of the button. It actually works in Chrome, Firefox and Safari(with horrid green) but again no joy in IE.

```
</script>

<!-- This script iterates through each line item int billing accordion and color codes by status-->
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

   document.getElementsByClassName('dueDate');
   document.getElementsByClassName('invoiceNo');
   document.getElementsByClassName('premium');
   var bills = document.getElementsByClassName('status');
   document.getElementsByTagName('button');

   for (i in bills) {
      var dueDate = document.getElementsByClassName('dueDate')[i];
      var invoiceNo = document.getElementsByClassName('invoiceNo')[i];
      var premium = document.getElementsByClassName('premium')[i];
      var status = document.getElementsByClassName('status')[i];
      var button = document.getElementsByName('button')[i];

      /* Mark bills due to be paid: Green */
      if (status.value == "DUE") {
         dueDate.style.color = 'green';
         invoiceNo.style.color = 'green';
         premium.style.color = 'green';
         status.style.color = 'green';
      }
      /* Mark bills unpaid and overdue: Red to signify ACTION REQUIRED */
      else if (status.value == "UNPAID") {
         dueDate.style.color = 'red';
         invoiceNo.style.color = 'red';
         premium.style.color = 'red';
         status.style.color = 'red';
      }
      else {
         button.style.display = 'none';
         <!-- Error here:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined-->
      }
   }
});
</script>
```

I am also looking for a good online tutorial with concrete examples on debugging in Chrome, if anybody knows of one. The one provided by Google is a bit vague.

UPDATE:

Ok I have followed the suggestion to console.log the i variable and then set a breakpoint on it.

I stepped through this with Chrome dev tools and the script executes correctly through each iteration to colour each line correctly. When done though it seems to iterate two more times for length and status as indicated in the console:

```
testjs.html:80 1
testjs.html:80 2
testjs.html:80 length
testjs.html:80 status
```

When it is in at:

status/dueDate.style.color = "green";

I get - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Hmmm. For all intents and purposes the end result looks correct in Chrome/Safari, slightly off, in terms of colours, in Safari and just doesn't work at all in Internet Explorer.
I ran the debugger in IE and for some reason when stepping through it just jumps past the conditionals status.value == "DUE"  and status.value == "UNPAID" as if these don't apply.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use `jQuery.css` method ?

Comment: Maybe its for(i in bills) try to console.log(i) and see. Open the console with f12

Answer (score 0):

Sorted:

I changed how the loop iterated over the bills by using the more traditional format of:

```
for (i = 0; i < bills.length; i++)
```

I attempted some debugging with some success to discover that the for in version was going out of bounds by adding extra runs through the loop for some reason.

Everything in Internet explorer renders nicely now.

The last thing to sort out is Safari rendering font colours oddly when using this script compared to how other browsers handle it.